# Already set CUDA_PROFILE=1 and COMPUTE_PROFILE=1, but no log file output?

Tags: command-line, cuda, profiler

Two A100 cards installed on the system. Attempt to use the CUDA Cmd-Line profiler. Run the simplest example of CUDA. Type the command

```
export COMPUTE_PROFILE=1
export CUDA_PROFILE=1
./simpleMultiGPU
```

output

```
Starting simpleMultiGPU
CUDA-capable device count: 2
Generating input data...

Computing with 2 GPUs...
  GPU Processing time: 7.483000 (ms)

Computing with Host CPU...

Comparing GPU and Host CPU results...
  GPU sum: 16777280.000000
  CPU sum: 16777294.395033
  Relative difference: 8.580068E-07
```

But there is no log file output. Type

```
ls -a
```

Still output

```
.  ..  Makefile  NsightEclipse.xml  readme.txt  simpleMultiGPU  simpleMultiGPU.cu  simpleMultiGPU.h  simpleMultiGPU.o
```

What could be the cause? Thanks in advance!

Comment: command line profiling support was dropped a lot time ago AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line profiler you are attempting to use isn't part of any CUDA toolkit that supports GPUs like A100.  It was deprecated and removed some time ago (it was removed prior to CUDA 8.0.  CUDA 11.x or newer is required for A100 support).

The recommended profilers are nsight compute and nsight systems.  A set of introductory blogs starts [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/migrating-nvidia-nsight-tools-nvvp-nvprof/).

Comment: So you mean we can profile events as memory copy from cpu and gpu  and vice versa and CUDA kernel function calls by the tools(nsys, nv-nsight-cu-cli) that migrated from nvprof?

Comment: Yes, you can profile those things using the tools nsight compute and nsight systems.